# Match column and row, then print data

Tags: php

I am having two set off arrays, first array is holding data about colors, second about dimensions.

```
$colors= array(
"27" => "RAL 9002", 
"255" => "RAL 9006", 
"341" => "RAL 8019", 
"286" => "RAL 7016", 
"141" => "RAL 3009",  
"171" => "RAL 6028", 
"121" => "RAL 8004", 
"221" => "RAL 5010",
"101" => "RAL 3000", 
"273" => "RAL 9007",); 

$dimensions =  array
  (
  array(0.3,1245),
  array(0.35,1245),
  array(0.40,1100),
  array(0.45,1245),
  array(0.50,1245),
  array(0.60,1245),
  array(0.70,1245), 
  );
```

Values above are used for queries. I wanted to make an array which will hold data, and later in comparison will print data. Query can return result NULL

```
foreach($colors as $key => $value)
    {
        //print "Boja $key .  <br>";
    foreach($dimensions as $data )
        {
            //print "Debljina $data[0], Sirina $data[1] Boja $key  <br>";
            $sql = "SELECT   Debljina,  Sirina, sum(Kolicina) as suma 
            FROM jos_ib_repromaterijali WHERE  Debljina = '$data[0]' AND  Sirina = '$data[1]' AND Boja = '$key'";

            $q = $conn -> query($sql);

            $vrijednosti = array();
            while($r=$q->fetch()) {

                $debljina = $r['Debljina'];
                $sirina = $r['Sirina'];
                $kolicina = $r['suma'];

                $vrijednosti[] = $debljina . $sirina . $kod . $kolicina;

            }
        }
    }
```

Once I get results, I create html table

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th><?php echo "Dimenzije"; ?> </th>
            <?php foreach($colors as $boja) { ?>            
            <th><?php echo $boja; ?> </th> 
            <?php  } ?>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($dimensions as $dim) { 

       ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $dim[0] . ' X ' . $dim[1]; ?>  </td> 
            <td><?php
             if (isset($vrijednosti[$dim[0] . $dim[1]])) {  

                echo "asdas";

            }  
            else {
                echo "error";
            }
            ?>  </td> 
        </tr>
        <?php }

    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table print headers and dimensions as it should, I am having trouble in matching rows with column. If someone give me an advice it would be appreciated. 
Query can give result NULL; if that is result It should print 0 below color for specific row.

[image]

Comment: You are comparing `Debljina = "0.3"` but db values is like `0.3X1245`

Comment: you should use keyword like or combine both values from dimensions arr